# Pass Flask values to HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend

I am trying to pass a variable through Flask to my HTML page

```
@app.route("/<youtubeUrl>/", methods=["POST","GET"])
def results(youtubeUrl):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect(url_for("results", youtubeUrl=request.form["url"], link=str(youtubeUrl)))
    else:
        return render_template("result.html")
```

But when I put this on my HTML, it is not printed:

```
<p>{{ link }}</p>
```

As you can see I also tried to do a cast to string, but it still not being printed.

Comment: what parameters are you passing on "results"? Because you are redirecting to it. When you render_template on "results" make sure you pass link on it.

Comment: I've rewrote the question with the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `link` var is never passed to the template.  Your redirect sends a GET request.  You need to send the `link` along with it:

```
else:
    template_context = {
        link : request.args.get('link'),
        youtubeUrl : youtubeUrl
    }
    return render_template("result.html", **template_context)
```

> NOTE:  The extra number of keywords arguments passed to the url_for()
> function will be appended to the URL as a query string.

Comment: Thank you GAEfan!! That's it, I was not passing the variable to the GET request :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the name of the html file

```py
return redirect(url_for("results.html", youtubeUrl=request.form["url"], link=str(youtubeUrl)))
```

Comment: Thank you ReetS, but the variable still not being printed on the HTML